# How to get the selected activity in rehosted WorkflowDesigner

Tags: .net, wpf, selection, workflow-foundation-4, rehosting

How do I get (programatically) the current selection? As an `Activity` instance, if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Activity activity = workflowDesigner.Context.Items.GetValue<Selection>().
    PrimarySelection.GetCurrentValue() as Activity;
```